# Перенос комментариев в чат плохо создаёт пользователя

Tags: дефект, чат, инструменты-модератора, перенос-комментариев-в-чат

Есть [вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1027837/178988), заданный участником, имеющим нормально отображаемое имя и аватарку:

[image: скриншот автора вопроса]

и есть [ответ на него](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1027842/178988), под которым автор вопроса оставлял свои комментарии:

> [image: скриншот комментариев]

Я перенёс комментарии в [чат](//chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99227/discussion-on-answer-by-qwertiy-----), где можно увидеть:

> [image: скриншот чата]

Видно, что пользователь, являющийся автором вопроса, отображён как [user27189](//chat.stackexchange.com/users/429051/user271890), т. е. ни имя, ни аватарка, при создании пользователя чата, туда не скопировались:

[image: скриншот пользователя чата]

Comment: @edem, вроде нет. В любом случае, ты очень сильно испортил его смысл. 1. Переносятся все комментарии, а не только конкретного пользователя. 2. Если у этого пользователя ещё нет аккаунта в чате, перенос комментариев, похоже, инициирует создание учётной записи чата. 3. Именно у этой учётной записи отсутствуют имя и аватарка.

Comment: А, прошу прощения. Теперь понял, что речь про создание пользователя, но всё равно, воспринимается тяжко в такой подаче.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99229/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-edem).